# php 2 foreach result mixed

Tags: php, arrays

I have `2 array datas`, `("a","b","c")` and `("x","y","z")`, how to mixed them and out put a result as `(ax)|(ay)|(az)|(bx)|(by)|(bz)|(cx)|(cy)|(cz)`? (each `$array1 + $array2` combine into a new words).

```
$array1 = array("a","b","c");
foreach($array1 as $data1){

}
$array2 = array("x","y","z");
foreach($array2 as $data2){

}
//$output = '(ax)|(ay)|(az)|(bx)|(by)|(bz)|(cx)|(cy)|(cz)';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to use a nested loop:

```
$items = array();

foreach($array1 as $a)
{
    foreach($array2 as $b)
    {
        $items[] = '(' . $a . $b . ')';
    }
}
echo implode('|', $items); // (ax)|(ay)|(az)|(bx)|(by)|(bz)|(cx)|(cy)|(cz)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$array = array();
$array1 = array("a","b","c");
$array2 = array("x","y","z");
foreach($array1 as $data1){
 foreach($array2 as $data2){
  $array[] = '('.$data1.$data2.')';
 }
}
echo implode('|', $array);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
<?php

$array1 = array("a","b","c");
$array2 = array("x","y","z");

$array3 = array();

foreach($array1 as $data1){
    foreach($array2 as $data2){
        $array3[] = "($data1$data2)";
    }
}

echo implode('|', $array3);

// (ax)|(ay)|(az)|(bx)|(by)|(bz)|(cx)|(cy)|(cz)
```